# Paypal Mobile Checkout Example or detail Documentation

Tags: android, iphone, paypal, titanium, titanium-mobile

i have search & try a lot of stuff on the web.
But... i can´t find on detailt documentation or an example...

Maybe you have a link how helps me.
Many links on paypal site are dead and the same on x.com (developer section)

What would i like to do:

Iám programming an iphone app and also an android app.
Payment with paypal - was the plan.

I need an "webview" where i can link to my webserver and there the visitor can login in with paypal an buy. So i don´t need to develop a new way each operation system...

Iám really happy if someone could help me.
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: And what is your problem? Titanium provides a web view which can display remote pages.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a PayPal module for iOS & Android you can use out of the box.

When you download it, it will actually come with documentation & examples included.

You can find it here: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4978?1935393353